# Logistic map and chaos on a Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Searching about logistic map I've read many times that logistic map is chaotic for $r \geqslant 4$ on a Cantor set. Does that mean that chaos occurs only if $x_0$ (the starting point) belongs in that particular Cantor set?

Comment: I have no relevant reference at hand, and it's somewhat long to explain cleanly, so for now I'll just comment. For $r > 4$, the transformation is open: almost every point leaves the interval $[0,1]$. However, the set of points which never leaves $[0,1]$ is compact, invariant, and a Cantor set.

Comment: This invariant set is just $\bigcap_{n \geq 0} f^{-n} ([0,1])$. If you want to see why it's a Cantor, draw $[0,1]$, then $f^{-1} ([0,1])$, then $f^{-2} ([0,1])$, etc. You should see a pattern appear.

Comment: Finally, the dynamics of a point on the invariant set is conjugated to a full shift on two symbols (you can encode any point $x$ in this invariant set uniquely as a sequence 0.LLRLLL..., where the $n$th digit is R if and only if $f^n (x)$ belongs to the right part [1/2,1]$. Then the dynamics is just a shift on this sequence), which is chaotic.